# ImportError: No module named gconf when importing dogtail

Tags: python

I have successfully install dogtail 0.7.1.1 on my system but when I try to

```
from dogtail import tree
```

I get this error instead

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "appstartup.py", line 9, in ?  
    from dogtail.procedural import *                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/dogtail/procedural.py", line 18, in ?                                              
    import tree                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/dogtail/tree.py", line 66, in ?                                                    
    checkForA11y()                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/dogtail/utils.py", line 185, in checkForA11y                                       
    if not isA11yEnabled(): bailBecauseA11yIsDisabled()                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/dogtail/utils.py", line 158, in isA11yEnabled                                      
    import gconf                                                                                                        
ImportError: No module named gconf
```

I have used the below command to verify that gconf is available on my system. Have anyone encountered this problem?

```
> gconftool-2 --version                                                                                        
2.16.0
```

Comment: You need the [gcon module](https://pypi.org/project/gconf/) installed

Answer (score 1):

`pip install gconf` should fix it.